# Insert data in db from foreach using many arrays various length

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

Im trying to insert data from a form that looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="single_color_show[]" value="1" id="1" checked>
<input type="text" name="single_color_val[]" class="input-admin-val" value="0" id="1">
<input type="hidden" name="single_color_name[]" value="Vit: (NCS S0502-Y)" id="1">
<input type="hidden" name="single_color_head[]" value="colors" id="1">
<input type="hidden" name="single_color_standard[]" value="1" id="1">
<input type="hidden" name="single_color_order[]" value="1" id="1">
<input type="hidden" name="single_color[]" value="1" id="1"></td>
```

and so on...

What i want is all values to be stored in the db. This works fine as long as single_color_show is checked. But i need the data to be inserted regardless, but with a value of 0 instead of 1 so the script knows it should be hidden.

This is my php code:

```
$single_color_show = $_POST['single_color_show'];
$single_color = $_POST['single_color'];
$single_color_name = $_POST['single_color_name'];
$single_color_val = $_POST['single_color_val'];
$single_color_head = $_POST['single_color_head'];
$single_color_standard = $_POST['single_color_standard'];
$single_color_order = $_POST['single_color_order'];

foreach($single_color_order as $key => $n) {
$s_color = "INSERT INTO product_attributes (products_id, att_name, att_head, att_val, att_standard, att_order, att_show) VALUES ('".$products_id_enkel."', '".$single_color_name[$key]."', '".$single_color_head[$key]."', '".$single_color_val[$key]."', '".$single_color_standard[$key]."', '".$single_color_order[$key]."', '".$single_color_show[$key]."');";
$q = mysql_query($s_color) or die ('Error posting data enkeldörr färg');
}
```

As long as i leave all choises checked it saves the data beutiful, but since i need to retrieve the data for future edit i need all the presented choices to go with the choosen attributes.

If i check lets say 2 out of 3 choises i want the data to be stored as this

```
products_id, att_name, att_head, att_val, att_standard, att_order, att_show
12           Red       Color      80          1            1          1
12           Blue      Color      50          0            2          0
12           Green     Color      70          0            3          1
```

This is what i get now:

```
products_id, att_name, att_head, att_val, att_standard, att_order, att_show
12           Red       Color      80          1            1          1
12           Green     Color      70          0            3          1
```

Comment: +1 for nice supply of code etc. BUT: how is record with att_val = 50 different from the other records?

Comment: Is that sarcasm i hear?

Comment: @michi its not att_val that makes the foreach crash, its the fact that att_show has been unchecked in the form an therefore the array of $ingle_color_show has gotten less "rows" than the others, and that row isnt getting inserted into DB, which i neeeed!

Comment: I see. See my answer in a few secs

Comment: looking forward to it ;)

Comment: Please, please, read up on SQL injection and use mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work on the checkbox-HTML-code and the checkbox-array:

(1) HTML
Give each checkbox a unique `value`starting from 0:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="0"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="4"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="box[]" value="5"/>
```

(2) PHP
Handle the array after submit...

```
if (isset($_POST['box'])) {

    $max = count($_POST['single_color']); // get max number of elements in "full" array

    for ($i = 0;$i < $max;$i++)
        $box[$i] = intval(in_array($i,$_POST['box']));
} else $box = array();
```

(3) use mysqli_* or PDO instead of mysql_* ;-)

---> see live demo here : http://codepad.viper-7.com/jUPseH

Comment: Thanks man! I solved by replacing the checkbox with a select list with Show / hide preset to show. Works like a charm :)

Comment: @Martin: you had a good idea while I worked my butt off with your code ;-)

Comment: Yes, its crazy :) Ive spent the last 8 hours struggeling with this problem, and when i finally get a good answer, i come up with a good idea, im sorry man :) Really appreciate your effort though! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the single_color_show attribute a hidden field like the others and then use javascript to toggle it's value between 0 and 1 whenever the checkbox changes.